# Is there a Hyperopt equivalent for optimization in R?

Tags: machine-learning, python, r

I've used Hyperopt in Python, but I'm looking for a package with similar capabilities in R. Does a package like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to `DEoptim()`. This package might solve your problem. For the documentation and more information visit-

- [Documentation](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i06/paper)
- [CRAN-R : DEoptim()](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `hyperopt` directly through reticulate.  I've added a small wrapper on github: https://github.com/njnmco/hopticulate